# Selenium WebDriver (Java): How can I nest these NoSuchElement Exception tests?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

OS: Windows 7 32bit
ChromeDriver version: 2.30
Selenium Webdriver version: 3.4.0
Java 8

I've tried a few different ways to clean this code up and not have to repeat the same try/catch blocks. I'm trying to check that various elements are present on a page I'm testing. I can gracefully report to the console and this code does work with no problems. 
The issue I'm having is with the ungraceful code. Is there a way to nest these try/catch blocks, or put them inside of an if/else loop?

```
try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/head/title"));
            System.out.println("Title found...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.out.println("Title NOT FOUND...");
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logindiv']"));
            System.out.println("Login form found...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.out.println("Login form NOT FOUND...");
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
            System.out.println("'Username' field found...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.out.println("'Username' form NOT FOUND...");
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
            System.out.println("'Password' field found...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.out.println("'Password' form NOT FOUND...");
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("loginSubmit")).getText();
            System.out.println("Login button found...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.out.println("Login button NOT FOUND...");
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things...

1. I'm a firm believer that exceptions should be exceptional, meaning exceptions shouldn't be used as flow control. This is further supported [by the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-),

   > findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.

   so you should replace `.findElement()` and `try-catch` with `.findElements()` and test for empty. See example in #2.
2. You really should use some `Assert` library like JUnit, etc. It makes these validations so much easier/cleaner.

   This whole thing

   ```
   try
   {
       driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
       System.out.println("'Username' field found...");
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
   catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
   {
       System.out.println("'Username' form NOT FOUND...");
       // ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   should/could look like

   ```
   Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElements(By.id("username")).isEmpty(), "Validate Username field exists");
   ```
3. Arguments could be made that it's faster, so on and so forth but... it hurts me to see people use something complicated like an XPath to do no more than locate an element by ID, e.g. `By.xpath("//*[@id='logindiv']")`. This is so much simpler and easier to read as `By.id("logindiv")`.
4. You can do some googling to see all the details but `Thread.Sleep()` is a bad practice and should be avoided. Instead use `WebDriverWait`. Explore `ExpectedConditions` to see all what can be waited for and use it liberally. In the cases you posted in your code, I don't see any reason to wait for any of these so that's several seconds of unnecessary wasted time.
5. Your last example is pulling `.getText()` but not using it. Since you are just checking that the button exists, you can safely remove the `.getText()` from the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public void checkElementVisibile()throws InterruptedException {
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/head/title"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(isElementVisibile(element))
        System.out.println("Title found...");
    else
        System.out.println("Title not found...");
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logindiv']"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(isElementVisibile(element))
        System.out.println("Login form found...");
    else
        System.out.println("Login form not found...");
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
    if(isElementVisibile(element))
        System.out.println("'Username' field found...");
    else
        System.out.println("'Username' field not found...");
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(isElementVisibile(element))
        System.out.println("'Password' field found...");
    else
        System.out.println("'Password' field not found...");
}
public static boolean isElementVisibile(WebElement element){
    try {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    }catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```